# How to have only one active state showing dropdown and others false in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, next.js

I'm trying to make a dropdown navigation. The idea is to only have one active dropdown when the navigation is clicked and the others close. At the moment it works by the following concept I have but I'm stuck currently where both dropdown is open at the same time when both are clicked.

How can I toggle/add only have one active state and turn the other's separate function state to false ? please help..

```
export default function Header(args) {
    const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);
    const [isResourceActive, setResourceActive] = useState(false);
        
    const handleToggle = () => {setActive(!isActive);};
    const resourcesHandleToggle = () => {setResourceActive(!isResourceActive);};

         return (
    <NavItem onClick={handleToggle} className={isActive ? "active" : ""}></NavItem>  
    <NavItem onClick={resourcesHandleToggle} className={isResourceActive ? "active" :""}</NavItem>
        
        
        <div className={isActive ? "active": ""}>DROPDOWN_1</div>
        <div className={isResourceActive ?"active": ""}>DROPDOWN_2</div>
    )
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just force the false for the other dropp (or check it first with a "if" if u want)

```
const handleToggle = () => {    
    setActive(!isActive);
    setResourceActive(false);    
};
   

 const resourcesHandleToggle = () => {
    setResourceActive(!isResourceActive);
    setActive(false);    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [active, setActive] = useState(undefined);
```

```
const toggle = (name) => {
  if (active === name) {
    setActive(undefined)
  } else {
    setActive(name)
  }
}
```

```
<NavItem onClick={() => toggle('DROPDOWN_1')} className={active === 'DROPDOWN_1' ? "active" : ""}></NavItem>  
<NavItem onClick={() => toggle('DROPDOWN_2')} className={active === 'DROPDOWN_2' ? "active" :""}</NavItem>
<div className={active === 'DROPDOWN_1' ? "active": ""}>DROPDOWN_1</div>
<div className={active === 'DROPDOWN_2' ? "active": ""}>DROPDOWN_2</div>
```